# I want to use JsArray with the Webix component DataTable

Tags: javascript, web, datatable, webix

I want to use JsArray with the Webix component DataTable. But I have one problem. When I use JsArray format I can’t update the data in the Webix datagrid. Unfortunately, I can see only the beginning of its data. Check the sample to understand the issue:

```js
var array1 = [ [1,"Marie","Oslo"],[2,"John","Los Angeles"],[3,"Kate","London"] ];
var array2 = [ [4,"Martin","Manchester"],[5,"Joana","Lisbon"],[6,"Ronaldo","Barcelona"],[7,"Matthew","Portland"] ];
 
webix.ui({
    view:"button", 
    label:"test new data", 
    click: function() {
        new_data() 
    }
});
 
webix.ui({
    view:"datatable",
    id: "mytable",
    columns:[
        {id:"data0", header:"ID" },
        {id:"data1", header:"Name" },
        {id:"data2", header:"City" }    
    ],                                      
    datatype: "jsarray",                
    data: array1
});
 
function new_data () {
 
    var mytable = $$("mytable");
    mytable.parse(array2);
}
```

After pressing the button “test new data”, 4 new empty lines appear in the table.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you should specify data format in the parse command

```js
mytable.parse(array2, "jsarray");
```

The component will expect the json data, by default.

I hope that it'll help you)